# Django: module 'django_mysql.models' has no attribute 'JSONField'?

Tags: mysql, json, django-models

I'm running Django 4.0. I've got a models with fields declared like this:

```
industries = models.JSONField()
```

On MakeMigration, Django is throwing the error:

> module 'django_mysql.models' has no attribute 'JSONField'

There are at least 3 previous SO posts on this. They advise using Django's `models.JSONField()`, which I am doing.

I'm using:

- Django 4.0
- Python 3.9.13
- django-mysql 4.7.0

Why am I getting this error message?

**Update**

Possibly relevant somehow: the error is being thrown in an old migration file from 2019.

Comment: Likely not with `django_mysql` for `models`, just with the `from django.db import models`.

Comment: I deleted all of the `from django.db.models import JSONField` statements. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: @VkR: No!, you somehow did `from django_mysql import models`, not `from django.db import models`.

Comment: A project-wide grep search for `from django_mysql import(.*)models` returns no results.

Comment: Wait, searching for `django_mysql.models` is turning things up! Checking...

Comment: Yes... it's in old migration files... `    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='xforcecollection',
            name='description',
            field=django_mysql.models.JSONField(default=dict),
        ),
    ]`.   I guess I have to open a new SO post to ask how to handle this.

Comment: If you'd like to post your advice in the form of an answer, I can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Willem Van Onsem for the answer. He pointed out that I must still be referencing `django_mysql.models.JSONField` somehow. Sure enough, I had old migration files that were doing that. (And [here's the SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777143/django-updating-old-migration-files-that-have-django-mysql-models-jsonfield/72778112#72778112) about how to fix that.)

@Willem, if you'd like to post your comment in the form of an answer here, I will mark it as the accepted answer.