# Django: Updating Old Migration Files that Have `django_mysql.models.JSONField`?

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

In older versions of Django, you could use JSON fields in models via `django_mysql.models.JSONField`.  In new versions of Django, JSONField is no longer in `django_mysql.models`.  I've updated my models.py files accordingly, but I still have old migrations files that look like this:

```
# Generated by Django 2.1.7 on 2019-07-17 22:59

from django.db import migrations
import django_mysql.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('rss', '0009_delete_patternmatchingkeywords'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='rssoutput',
            name='industries',
            field=django_mysql.models.JSONField(default=list), ##<== ERROR
        ),
    ]
```

Now when I run `makeMigration`, I get this error:

> AttributeError: module 'django_mysql.models' has no attribute 'JSONField'

What is the correct procedure to address this?

I'm using:

- Django 4.0
- Python 3.9.13
- django-mysql 4.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change it to proper `JSONField` that Django suggests:

```
from django.db.models import JSONField

...

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...    
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            ...
            field=JSONField(default=list)
        ),
    ]
```